# sass doesn't compile: Seg Fault error

Tags: ruby, sass

i'm getting this error when i try to compile a scss file with:

```
sass test.scss test.css
```

the error in particulary is:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.2/lib/sass/util.rb:637: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

I installed Ruby and Sass via gem. Reinstalling and creating an empty `test.css` didn't solve the problem.

this is the scss file:

```
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333

body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Post your sass file as well. Also try removing bits of the sass file and see when it stops failing so you will know what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your extension is right! If you use the indented syntax, use `.sass`, otherwise use `.scss`. Fixing that lets it compile as expected for me.

Comment: change the extensions to sass but the error still remains

Comment: Did you just run `sass test.sass`, or something else? I'm unable to reproduce the error you're getting.

Comment: i did "sass test.sass test.css"

Comment: Just try `sass test.sass`. The only file you want to compile is the sass one.

Comment: I've got nothing, as there's clearly something on your end that I can't reproduce.

Comment: i dont know what could be, i simply follow the tutorial, this happen with scss and sass file

Comment: What tutorial? You never mentioned that.